# php accessing attributes in json

Tags: php, json

I have the following already decoded json stored in `$response = $result->response;`:

```
 object(stdClass)#6 (5) {
  ["EmailAddress"]=> string(18) "email@gmail.com"
  ["Name"]=> string(0) ""
  ["Date"]=> string(19) "2011-10-09 19:32:00"
  ["State"]=> string(6) "Active"
  ["CustomFields"]=> array(1) {
    [0]=>object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
            ["Key"]=>string(2) "id"
            ["Value"]=>string(6) "Dl9lIz"
    }
  }
```

I can already access the main attributes (EmailAddress, Name, etc) with:

```
$email = $response->{'EmailAddress'};
print $email;
```

But I need to access the `"Value"` portion in the CustomFields object. I don't know how to dig that deep. I'm attempting to do this in PHP..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is contained in the first element (`[0]`) of array `CustomFields`, so you can access it with an object operator (`->`) after the array index.

```
print $response->CustomFields[0]->Value;
```