# Echo CustomField from nested array object in PHP

Tags: php, object

I've read this excellent answer; [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, I can't seem to extract the object value I need from a nested array. I'm using the campaign monitor API and it dumps out the following objects.  I need to be able to echo or print_r the "Phone" custom field value:

This is what my query is producing in a var_dump($result->response);

```
Got subscriber

object(stdClass)#728 (6) {
  ["EmailAddress"]=>
  string(29) "example@mail.com"
  ["Name"]=>
  string(7) "Alan"
  ["Date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-10-07 17:10:00"
  ["State"]=>
  string(6) "Active"
      ["CustomFields"]=>
        array(4) {
        [0]=>
           object(stdClass)#727 (2) {
            ["Key"]=>
            string(5) "Phone"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(7) "12345678"
    }
[snip]
```

How to echo or print_r the phone number by selecting "Key" string and grabbing the "Value" string? I've tried below (and variations) but not working;

```
foreach($result->response->CustomFields as $CustomField) {
    if(!empty($CustomField->Key->Phone)) {
         $phone = $CustomField->Key->Phone->Value;
    }

echo 'test phone'. $phone;

}
```

The following DOES work (similar to this thread [php accessing attributes in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000412/php-accessing-attributes-in-json)) - however, the problem with using the integer [2] in the below is that it can potentially change to a different key, depending on number of fields in the array that a given user has populated - so this method is unreliable;

```
print_r($result->response->CustomFields[2]->Value);
```

Comment: `$CustomField->Key` is not an object with another `->Phone`, it's a string! You probably want `if ($CustomField->Key == 'Phone')`!?

Comment: Thanks. I tried but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you do this:

```
foreach($result->response->CustomFields as $CustomField) {
```

You can access the fields like this:

```
$CustomField->Key
$CustomField->Value
```

So if you want to process it further, you can do for example something like this:

```
$someClass->{$CustomField->Key} = $CustomField->Value
```

Which translates to: *$someClass->Phone = "12345678"* . It pretty much depends on what you really want to do next with the values.

Comment: This looks helpful, however I wasn't able to get it working.  In this example, how would I specify the key to be "phone". I tried this: if ($CustomField->Key == 'Phone') {
    echo 'test phone'. $CustomField->Value;
          }

Comment: @Sol, key of what? How do you intend to use it?? You already know the key, it's: `$CustomField->Key`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting that. I simply want to target the "Key" > "Phone" and extract the phone number.  Can you provide a clearer example ?

Comment: @Sol, what isn't working with this code `if ($CustomField->Key == 'Phone') { echo 'test phone'. $CustomField->Value; }` ?

Comment: Well now, that's the same code I was using - and now it is working.... very strange!!   Super moon madness.  Thanks for your help walther ;)